# [MCAdvertiserAssistant advertiser:didNotStartAdvertisingPeer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

The issue was started appearing along with iOS 14.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MCAdvertiserAssistant advertiser:didNotStartAdvertisingPeer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2810c58f0'

All I do in code is:

```
func setupConnectivity() {
    peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: Settings.shared.myName)
    mcSession = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .required)
    mcSession.delegate = self
    mcAdvertiserAssistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "hws-kb", discoveryInfo: nil, session: mcSession)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is sufficient to insert in the info.plist the following fields:

[image]